# How can I copy opcodes from a method to another method in Java Class file using ASM?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

Here are some code.

```
static synchronized void q(ua paramua, int paramInt) {
try {
 if (d) { if (paramInt > -16711936);
   return; }
 if (q * 514194583 > 0) { if (paramInt > -16711936);
   abf localabf = new abf(paramua);
   n.d(localabf, -984409319);
 }
 else {
   paramua.ma(false);
 }
 return; } catch (RuntimeException localRuntimeException) { throw aht.d(localRuntimeException, "ck.q(" + 41);
}
}

static synchronized void b(ua paramua)
{
  if (d) return;
  if (q * 514194583 > 0) {
    abf localabf = new abf(paramua);
    n.d(localabf, -836239689);
  }
  else {
    paramua.ma(false);
  }
}
```

These two methods performs equal actions.
The second parameter of the first method is psudo-argument, so I want to clear original code and make this method like this...

```
static synchronized void q(ua paramua, int paramInt)
{
  if (d) return;
  if (q * 514194583 > 0) {
    abf localabf = new abf(paramua);
    n.d(localabf, -836239689);
  }
  else {
    paramua.ma(false);
  }
}
```

How can I do this action?
I tried like this.

```
destMethodNode.instructions.clear();
destMethodNode.instructions.add(srcMethodNode.instructions);
```

But throws null pointer exception. What is the reason?

Comment: I would edit the source and re-compile it. It is far more likely to work. To answer your question, you cannot add a list to list, perhaps addAll() is what you intended?

Comment: Why is assembly involved in this?

Comment: Please provide the stack trace for NPE you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

See "Merging Two Classes into One" section of paper from AOSD'07 linked from the ASM's [project page](http://asm.ow2.org/). It provides example how to properly use MethodNode to copy method's bytecode into another method.